# Storing more than 1 data item at a java LinkedList nodes and showing them

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I need to make a LinkedList in Java. I want that in every node, 8 data items stays stored, so when the next subject register that node stores that 8 data items.

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190380/storing-more-than-1-data-item-at-a-single-index-in-a-linked-list) answer to get a reference on how do this and I think I do it right, but when I use option 4, the list it's not seen on screen.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

class PaqueteDeDatos
{
   String Nombre;
   String Apellido;
   String Cedula;
   String Direccion;
   String Telefono;
   String CorreoElectronico;
   String Intensivo1;
   String Intensivo2;

   public PaqueteDeDatos(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g, String h) {
       Nombre = a;
        Apellido = b;
        Cedula = c;
        Direccion = d;
        Telefono = e;
        CorreoElectronico = f;
        Intensivo1 = g;
        Intensivo2 = h;
   }
}

public class Proyecto{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐");
        System.out.println ("│                               Manejo de listas dinamicas en Java                                       │");
        System.out.println ("├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤");
        System.out.println ("│Aplicacion que controla la informacion asociada a estudiante a inscribirse en un posible curso intensivo│");
        System.out.println ("└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘");
        //Pausa();
        for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
        LinkedList<PaqueteDeDatos> ListaDeAlumnos = new LinkedList<PaqueteDeDatos>();
        Iterator Iterador = ListaDeAlumnos.iterator();
        MenuPrincipal();
        Scanner CapturaDeDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("Introduzca su opcion: ");
        char Opcion = CapturaDeDatos.next().charAt(0);
        if ((int) Opcion !=53 && (int) Opcion !=52 && (int) Opcion !=51 && (int) Opcion !=50 && (int) Opcion !=49) {
            System.out.println("Opcion invalida. Por favor introduzca nuevamente su eleccion...");
            Pausa();
            for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
            MenuPrincipal();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca su opcion: ");
            Opcion = CapturaDeDatos.next().charAt(0);
        }
        if ((int) Opcion ==49) {
            for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el nombre del alumno: ");
            String Nombre = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el apellido del alumno: ");
            String Apellido = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el numero de cedula del alumno: ");
            String Cedula = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca la direccion de habitacion del alumno: ");
            String Direccion = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el telefono de contacto del alumno: ");
            String Telefono = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el correo electronico del alumno: ");
            String CorreoElectronico = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("A continuacion introduzca los intensivos a cursar por el alumno, basandose en la tabla superior.");
            System.out.println ("Tenga en cuenta que solo se pueden inscribir MAXIMO 2 intensivos. Para evitar retrazos en el inicio");
            System.out.println ("de los intensivos, procure que los intensivos escogidos por el alumno no choquen entre si");
            System.out.println ("por tener los mismos horarios. Introduzca 00 (2 ceros) luego del primer intensivo, si el alumno solo");
            System.out.println ("va a cursar un intensivo...");
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el codigo del intensivo seleccionado por el alumno: ");
            String Intensivo1 = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el codigo del intensivo seleccionado por el alumno: ");
            String Intensivo2 = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            PaqueteDeDatos Alumno = new PaqueteDeDatos (Nombre,Apellido,Cedula,Direccion,Telefono,CorreoElectronico,Intensivo1,Intensivo2);
            ListaDeAlumnos.add(Alumno);
            System.out.println ("Alumno inscrito exitosamente.");
            System.out.println ("El sistema regresara al menu principal en 5 segundos...");
            Pausa();
            for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
            MenuPrincipal();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca su opcion: ");
            Opcion = CapturaDeDatos.next().charAt(0);
        }
//        if ((int) Opcion ==50) {
//
//        }
  //      if ((int) Opcion ==51) EliminarAlumno();
        if ((int) Opcion ==52) {
            while (Iterador.hasNext())
                System.out.println (Iterador.next());
            System.out.println ("Listado de alumnos mostrado exitosamente.");
            System.out.println ("El sistema regresara al menu principal en 5 segundos...");
            Pausa();
            for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
            MenuPrincipal();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca su opcion: ");
            Opcion = CapturaDeDatos.next().charAt(0);
        }
        if ((int) Opcion ==53) System.exit(0);

    }

    // Metodo para la pausa en pantalla
    private static void Pausa() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

       // Metodo para el menu principal
    private static void MenuPrincipal() {
        System.out.println ("╔════════════════════╗");
        System.out.println ("║         Menu Principal        ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║                               ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║       Inscribir Alumno    (1) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║       Modificar Alumno    (2) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║       Eliminar Alumno     (3) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║ Mostrar Alumnos Inscritos (4) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║      Salir del sistema    (5) ║");
        System.out.println ("╚════════════════════╝");
        System.out.println ();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Convention is that variable names start with lower case letters. 2) Just compare `Opcion` to the actual characters instead of casting to an int and comparing to the ascii value. 3) It also isn't very clear what your actual question is and where you are having issues.

Comment: 1. You're right, but I code that way so I can understand my own code. 2. Thank you, I forgot to change that. 3. What I need is to add 6 students (each as a node), each one is going to "contain" 8 data items (first name, last name, SSN, address, phone, e-mail and 2 codes for 2 lessons the student want to take. After I add the six students I need go to option 4 and show all students and its personal data (that's it, I need to show all 8 data items contained in all 6 nodes). I also need to modify a data item inside a node and even delete a whole node...

Comment: *"You're right, but I code that way so I can understand my own code."* - This is BAD PRACTICE.  You should code so that other people can understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really hard to understand.  But if you are asking why the `ListaDeAlumnos` list appears to have nothing in it, the answer is that *you didn't put anything in it*.

It you want to put an element into a list, you need to use one of the `add`, `insert` or  `replace` methods.  Please refer to the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) javadocs or a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) on using Java collections for details.

Comment: You are quite right men, sorry, my mistake. After 18 hours stright coding in java even you will start to feel dizzy and forget to add a line or two. As you said, I did not add nothing to `ListaDeAlumnos` list. Now, if I add `ListaDeAlumnos.add(Alumno);` it add it to the list, but after choosing option 4 on the menu, I can't get anything on screen but a crash (with an Iterator). If I use a `System.out.println (ListaDeAlumnos.getLast());` instead of an Iterator I get "PaqueteDeDatos@1fdc96c", wich of course, is NOT what I put inside of ANY of the nodes...

Comment: That is most likely because you are modifying the list after creating the iterator.  (You'll get a ConcurrentModificationException).  And the "...@..." stuff is printed because that is what the default version of `toString` gives you.  If you want something pretty, you'll have to override the `toString()` method in your `PaqueteDeDatos` class.

Comment: Ok, I solved the crash but I still can't get rid of the ...@... thing. Did I mention that I REALLY hate Java?, no seriously, I did not understand what you mean with _"If you want something pretty, you'll have to override the toString() method in your PaqueteDeDatos class."_

Comment: @user605921 - guess what.  **I don't care** if you hate Java.  That's your problem, not mine.  Get out your Java text book and read up on "method overriding".  Then go to the javadocs and read what they says about 1) what `PrintStream.print(Object)` does, and 2) what `Object.toString()` does.

Comment: I don't have a java text book, that's why I'm asking here. I do read the stupid javadoc about `toStream()` and read a bunch of examples on the net, but all of them didn't take me farther away than your suggestion, mostly because as far as I had read, `toString()` requires a class and a object that "convert" to a readble string the object hash. For me, that doesn't work because I need to use `Iterator` to read all the node. How can I do that if I had to `ToStringClass tsc2 = new ToStringClass("Jane", "Doe");` and then `System.out.println("Class with toString() method    : " + tsc2);`???

Comment: I mean, I can't mix `System.out.println (Iterador.next());` and `System.out.println("Class with toString() method : " + tsc2);`, can I?. I don't think so, mostly because what I print with `System.out.println` is the content of my `Iterator` that is the 8 data items contained in my object...

Comment: "I don't have a Java textbook" - well buy one.  Or go to the Java website and read through the free Java tutorial.  You cannot learn a language properly by just looking at examples, and guessing what they might mean.

Comment: "well buy one" that's very easy for you to say, and VERY arrogant btw. you have money? good for you, now wake up and smell the coffe: not everyone have money to buy books, or programs or things like that, that's why there is a bad thing called PIRACY. Right now I need is guidance, not getting spanked. Anyway, that doesn't answer my question about how to use `toString()` in an `Iterator`...