# Storing more than 1 data item at a java LinkedList node and showing them as string with .toString()

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm doing a programming project that goes like this:

A system that handles the registration of students. At registration you must provide first and last name, identification number, address, phone, e-mail, and code of 2 lessons to sign up. This should be stored in a LinkedList.

Because each node in a LinkedList can store ONE data only I decided to go one step further. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190380/storing-more-than-1-data-item-at-a-single-index-in-a-linked-list) answer as a base I make a change, instead of storing the 8 students data for each student 8 in 8 consecutive nodes for each student enrolled, I made an object with 8 attributes, which stores the 8 data of the registration of each student, so when you want to delete a student simply delete the node containing the object instead of deleting 8 consecutive nodes for each student to be deleted.

The idea works perfect when I add the student data on the object and then on the LinkedList node, however, when I need to show on screen all the students is when the technique fails.

In theory by using an iterator methods .hasNext() and .Next() the list would iterate and show on screen the content of the objects stored in the nodes, and it does... but in hash instead of a String (what I need). So, on the screen, instead of displaying something like

```
Angel Pérez 15956228 7274205 skyx26@yahoo.com Caracas
Carolina Rojas 13508200 6253241 caro_caro27@hotmail.com Maracaibo
```

I get

```
PaqueteDeDatos@158b649
PaqueteDeDatos@127734f
```

After much searching I was told (here) that happens because

> And the "...@..." stuff is printed because that is what the default version of toString gives you. If you want something pretty, you'll have to override the toString() method in your `PaqueteDeDatos` class

Problem is that I can not use an iterator to display the contents of all nodes at the same time to make the override `.toString ()`.

Help me with this please, **I need to display the contents of the nodes of the linkedList as string and not as hash**.

Please please please explain me as easy as you can what I need to do to solve this, I don't really understand Java, I can't buy a book to understand it nor go to a public library to get one. I don't have friends who code in java so I can't ask for help to anyone and I need to get this done in the next 24 hours.

And please be constructive and kind. I don't really need to be spanked because I don't follow conventions or go to java site and follow tutorials before start coding in java. In fact I know all that but this is a rush situation and I running blind trying to pass this class because my programming teacher haven't teach me ANYTHING at all.

I'm using the code below (ONLY OPTIONS 1, 4 and 5 WORKS):

```
import java.util.*;

class PaqueteDeDatos {
    String Nombre;
    String Apellido;
    String Cedula;
    String Direccion;
    String Telefono;
    String CorreoElectronico;
    String Intensivo1;
    String Intensivo2;

   public PaqueteDeDatos(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g, String h) {
       Nombre = a;
       Apellido = b;
       Cedula = c;
       Direccion = d;
       Telefono = e;
       CorreoElectronico = f;
       Intensivo1 = g;
       Intensivo2 = h;
   }
}


public class Proyecto{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐");
        System.out.println ("│                               Manejo de listas dinamicas en Java                                       │");
        System.out.println ("├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤");
        System.out.println ("│Aplicacion que controla la informacion asociada a estudiante a inscribirse en un posible curso intensivo│");
        System.out.println ("└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘");
        //Pausa();
        LinkedList<PaqueteDeDatos> ListaDeAlumnos = new LinkedList<PaqueteDeDatos>();
        while (true) {
        for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();


        MenuPrincipal();
        Scanner CapturaDeDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("Introduzca su opcion: ");
        char Opcion = CapturaDeDatos.next().charAt(0);
        if (Opcion !='1' && Opcion !='2' && Opcion !='3' && Opcion !='4' && Opcion !='5') {
            System.out.println("Opcion invalida. Por favor introduzca nuevamente su eleccion...");
            Pausa();
        }
        if (Opcion =='1') {
            for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el nombre del alumno: ");
            String Nombre = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el apellido del alumno: ");
            String Apellido = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el numero de cedula del alumno: ");
            String Cedula = CapturaDeDatos.next();
                System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca la direccion de habitacion del alumno: ");
            String Direccion = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el telefono de contacto del alumno: ");
            String Telefono = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el correo electronico del alumno: ");
            String CorreoElectronico = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("A continuacion introduzca los intensivos a cursar por el alumno, basandose en la tabla superior.");
            System.out.println ("Tenga en cuenta que solo se pueden inscribir MAXIMO 2 intensivos. Para evitar retrazos en el inicio");
            System.out.println ("de los intensivos, procure que los intensivos escogidos por el alumno no choquen entre si");
            System.out.println ("por tener los mismos horarios. Introduzca 00 (2 ceros) luego del primer intensivo, si el alumno solo");
            System.out.println ("va a cursar un intensivo...");
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el codigo del intensivo seleccionado por el alumno: ");
            String Intensivo1 = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca el codigo del intensivo seleccionado por el alumno: ");
            String Intensivo2 = CapturaDeDatos.next();
            System.out.println ();
            PaqueteDeDatos Alumno = new PaqueteDeDatos (Nombre,Apellido,Cedula,Direccion,Telefono,CorreoElectronico,Intensivo1,Intensivo2);
            ListaDeAlumnos.add(Alumno);
            System.out.println ("Alumno inscrito exitosamente.");
            System.out.println ("El sistema regresara al menu principal en 5 segundos...");
            Pausa();
        }
//        if (Opcion =='2') {
//
//        }
  //      if (Opcion =='3') EliminarAlumno();
        if ((int) Opcion =='4') {
            Iterator Iterador = ListaDeAlumnos.iterator();
            while (Iterador.hasNext())
                System.out.println (Iterador.next());
            System.out.println ("Listado de alumnos mostrado exitosamente.");
            System.out.println ("El sistema regresara al menu principal en 5 segundos...");
            Pausa();
            for (int i=0; i<25; ++i) System.out.println();
            MenuPrincipal();
            System.out.print ("Introduzca su opcion: ");
            Opcion = CapturaDeDatos.next().charAt(0);

        }
        if (Opcion =='5') System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    // Metodo para la pausa en pantalla
    public static void Pausa() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

       // Metodo para el menu principal
    public static void MenuPrincipal() {
        System.out.println ("╔════════════════════╗");
        System.out.println ("║         Menu Principal        ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║                               ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║       Inscribir Alumno    (1) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║       Modificar Alumno    (2) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║       Eliminar Alumno     (3) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║ Mostrar Alumnos Inscritos (4) ║");
        System.out.println ("╠════════════════════╣");
        System.out.println ("║      Salir del sistema    (5) ║");
        System.out.println ("╚════════════════════╝");
            System.out.println ();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PaqueteDeDatos class should override the toString method so that instead of printing the hashCode, it will print the desired string.

```
class PaqueteDeDatos 
{
 String Nombre;
 String Apellido; 
 String Cedula; 
 String Direccion;
 String Telefono;
 String CorreoElectronico;
 String Intensivo1;
 String Intensivo2;

 public PaqueteDeDatos(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g, String h) 
 {
  Nombre = a;
  Apellido = b;
  Cedula = c;
  Direccion = d;
  Telefono = e;
  CorreoElectronico = f;
  Intensivo1 = g;
  Intensivo2 = h;
 }
 public String toString()
 {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(Nombre).append(" ")
    .append(Apellido).append(" ")
    .append(Cedula).append(" ")
    .append(Direccion).append(" ")
    .append(Telefono).append(" ")
    .append(CorreoElectronico).append(" ")
    .append(Intensivo1).append(" ")
    .append(Intensivo2).append(" ");
  return sb.toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: Men I LOVE YOU!!! I really do. You are my new hero, that's EXACTLY what I need. Thank you, thank you, thank you to the very end of time!

Comment: using a `StringBuilder` here has no advantage over using simple `String` concatenation.

Comment: @Joachim: Performance vise Yes! I put it since lot of properties are there for the object and for readability..

Comment: the readability can be argued (I find the direct version more readable). But what do you mean by "for the object"?

Comment: @aNish Performance-vise no, since in this case, compiler does that automatically. You can verify this by checking your bytecode.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to make a class printable or toString() able is to override the toString() method of the class. The simplest way to do this is to have your IDE generate the toString() method. Anything else is likely to be more difficult.

If you cannot change the code to add a toString() you can write your own method to convert a List of your objects to a String which inspects each element of the list and converts it how you want.